# How can I import a layout from another package in JavaFX?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

> Here is the code:

```
            package application;
            //imports
            import javafx.application.Application;
            import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
            import javafx.scene.Scene;
            import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
            import javafx.stage.Stage;
            import application.view.*; //i've tried import the package, but i don't know if this is correct



            public class Main extends Application {
                @Override
                public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                    try {
```

> //here is my issue:

```
                        **Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("application.view.Lay.fxml"));**

                        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
                        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                        primaryStage.show();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
```

> I've Tried this, but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?
>       Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/view/Lay.fxml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have a lengthy `package` name, we have to replace every dot "**.**" with forward slash.
Like if package name that contain views/fxml files is

```
package org.itsoftsolutions.view;
```

Than we have to provide path like this

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/org/itsoftsolutions/view/login.fxml"));
```